# Hide title if for statement is is empty

Tags: django

I have an image gallery for each users post. However, if a user has not uploaded any images I don't want to display the title "Image Gallery". How would I go about hiding the title if the for loop does not return anything?

```
<a>Image Gallery</a>
<div class="row">
    {% for images in postgallery %}
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="{{ images.images.url }}" data-lightbox="image-1">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ images.images.url }}" />
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I have tried a few variations of `{% if imagegallery == 0 %}` but I can't get anything to work as I would like

Comment: Try: `{% if postgallery|length == 0 %}`

Comment: @Alireza Please consider posting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`django doc`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#length) you can use this syntax: `{% if postgallery|length == 0 %}`